# Non-Retina resolution on newly created iOS App (Xamarin.Forms)?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I just created a new app with a MvvmCross template. But the iOS resolution looks like non-retina. Also, I only have i386 and x86_x64 as supported architectures and not ARM like all my other projects have. So what do I need to change that the app runs on the native resolution?

Has some one an idea what I need to change that the app stops looking like it was made for a 4" iPhone instead of a new app? Here are a few screenshots that may help to make clear what I mean (the App "PLZ Suche" is the one with the 'old' looking resolution, compared in the App Switcher it is clearly visible - all screenshots are taken on a iPhone 6S).

- Problem solved -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 'compatibility-mode' is triggered when you do not include a retina resolution splash screen (or launch screen as it is called in the Apple ecosystem) in your app.

Make sure that you have all the right types of splashscreens included in your app.

You can either:

- use a Storyboard (or XIB) that adapts to different screen resolutions automatically
- use XCode Asset catalog 'LaunchImage' image set, and fill all the correct sizes

You can read more about all the sizes and the launch screen on the [Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/).

Comment: Ah thanks for the reply. Thats explains a lot because all my other Apps uses Storyboards as LaunchScreen and this one uses Images (because I was to lazy to update this from my app).